# Is it possible to override the .mustache-files that are in the Gollum-gem?

Tags: gollum-wiki

I'm asking myself if I can change the .mustache templates to use my own html in my Gollum-wiki. If so it doesn't seem to documented (or am I just blind?).

I mean this: https://github.com/gollum/gollum/blob/master/lib/gollum/templates/layout.mustache

Can I override it or is the only way to have a different markup to use a different wiki software?

Comment: I have no idea what this question means but it pleased me greatly to see it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can simply:

1. Make your changes to the templates you need and put them on a directory of your choice
2. Also copy any other (probably unmodified) templates that Gollum requires (this is a bit clunky, see [Gollum's issue #1221](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/1221)) to that directory
3. Specify the `template-dir` option when launching Gollum

That will make Gollum to search for templates **only** in that location. At the time of writing, there is no fallback template location, or a way to override single templates. In any case, just copying all templates to `template-dir` will do exactly what you need.